# R gt how to substitute zeros in the summary row

Tags: r, gt

Is there a way to substitute the zeros in the summary row similar to what the sub_zero function does to the body cells?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)

df <- tibble(
  group = c("A", "A", "B", "B"),
  year = c(1992, 1993,1992, 1993),
  val1 = c(1,2,0,0),
  val2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0)
)

df %>% 
  gt(rowname_col = "year",
     groupname_col = "group") %>% 
  summary_rows(
    groups = TRUE,
    columns = c(val1, val2),
    fns = list(~sum(., na.rm = TRUE)),
    formatter = fmt_number,
    decimals = 0
  ) %>% 
  sub_zero(columns = c(val1, val2),
           zero_text = "-")
```

[image: summary_rows with zeros]

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not correct, but might work for you until someone posts something better. I just calculated the summary outside of `gt` and then made the zero substitutions that you wanted and then bound the two dataframes. I had to mess with the style a little to get it to look like the true summary:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)

df <- tibble(
  group = c("A", "A", "B", "B"),
  year = c(1992, 1993,1992, 1993),
  val1 = c(1,2,0,0),
  val2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0)
)


df |>
  group_by(group)|>
  summarise(across(c(val1, val2), sum),
            year = max(year) +1) |>
  bind_rows(df) |>
  arrange(group, year) |>
  mutate(across(c(val1, val2), ~sub("^0$", "-", .)),
         year = ifelse(year == max(year), "sum", as.character(year)))|> 
  gt(rowname_col = "year",
     groupname_col = "group") |>
  tab_style(
    style = list(
      cell_borders(
        sides = c("top"),
        color = "lightgrey",
        weight = px(2)
      )
    ),
    locations = list(
      cells_body(
        columns = everything(),
        rows = year == "sum"
      )
    )
  )
```

Comment: Thanks to your answer. It helped me to rethink the problem. At the end, I realized that by changing the zero values to "NA",  I could use the  **missing_text = "-"** param in the _summary_row()_ function.